# Force.com IDE error 'NotAfter'

Tags: force.com, ide, metadata

Any idea what's causing this error?

> [image: http://omg.wthax.org/IDE_error.jpg]

It's happening on both the Force.com IDE and the Force.com plugin for Eclipse, on Windows XP 32 bit. Strangely it's ONLY happening for one particular environment (EE Production). All other production / sandbox environments are working fine.

I've googled the sh*t out of it with no joy. Any help appreciated as this is holding up a pretty major deployment.

Thanks

Comment: i doubt on this as some permission issue .For your user metadata is not being retrieved

Comment: Check your local system clock? If there's clock skew between you and salesforce it could possibly cause issues with authentication tokens.

Comment: Maybe your working on an extension on a package whose license is expired?

Comment: Thank you ca_peterson that was it! If you want to submit your post, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your local system clock? 
If there's clock skew between you and salesforce it could possibly cause issues with authentication tokens, I know it does with a number of authentication systems (like Kerberos) and I wouldn't be surprised if your sessionId was viewed as "expired" on your local system.